# Kerberose, get ticket using ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, kerberos

So I have to `kinit` as certain principal locally using his keytab.

Since the Kerberose kdc on remote server, which I reach with on vpn, I need to use `ssh` to access the server, and thus make tunneling to the service.

For this I did the following:

1. Copied the krb5.conf from the remote server and replaced the local with it
2. Copied the keytab of my interest
3. Since I need access to the service:

   ```
   ssh -L1088:localhost:88 -L10749:localhost:749 remote_server
   ```
4. Changed the local file krb5.conf to

   ```
   admin_server = localhost:10749
   kdc = localhost:1088
   ```

But when I try to kinit

```
KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout kinit -kt ${PRINCIPAL_KEYTAB}.keytab ${PRINCIPAL_NAME}
[12332] 1504171391.121253: Getting initial credentials for ${PRINCIPAL_NAME}
[12332] 1504171391.123940: Looked up etypes in keytab: des, des-cbc-crc, aes128-cts, rc4-hmac, aes256-cts, des3-cbc-sha1                                                                                                                
[12332] 1504171391.124027: Sending request (227 bytes) to ${DOMAIN}                                  
[12332] 1504171391.124613: Resolving hostname localhost                                                             
[12332] 1504171391.124988: Sending initial UDP request to dgram ::1:1088                                            
[12332] 1504171391.125070: Sending initial UDP request to dgram 127.0.0.1:1088                                      
[12332] 1504171391.125120: Initiating TCP connection to stream ::1:1088                                             
[12332] 1504171391.125165: Terminating TCP connection to stream ::1:1088                                            
[12332] 1504171391.125186: Initiating TCP connection to stream 127.0.0.1:1088                                       
[12332] 1504171391.125216: Terminating TCP connection to stream 127.0.0.1:1088                                      
kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm '${DOMAIN}' while getting initial credentials
```

5. I retried by adding `ssh -vvv` and got

   ```
   debug1: Connection to port 1088 forwarding to localhost port 88 requested.
   debug2: fd 15 setting TCP_NODELAY
   debug2: fd 15 setting O_NONBLOCK
   debug3: fd 15 is O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: channel 7: new [direct-tcpip]
   debug3: send packet: type 90
   debug1: Connection to port 1088 forwarding to localhost port 88 requested.
   debug2: fd 16 setting TCP_NODELAY
   debug2: fd 16 setting O_NONBLOCK
   debug3: fd 16 is O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: channel 8: new [direct-tcpip]
   debug3: send packet: type 90
   ```

I tried to tcpdump, and locally there are tries to connect, but cannot find any packages received to the other site.

I edit out all other information in the krb5.conf.

What I am missing here or is this possible at all?

PS:
`netstat` says the ports are existing and opened on both machines.
I have no problem to `kinit` on the server itself.

PSS:
From what I see the kdc is actually listening at port `udp 88` not tcp, could this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it after all by using `socat` and `ssh` as follows, and several tutorials:

We are receiving `udp` packages to 1088, but `ssh` tunnels only `tcp`, so with `socat` we can "transform" them:

```
locally$ socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:1088,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:1089
```

Now we create ssh tunnel of that port to the remote server by

```
locally$ ssh -L1089:localhost:1089 remote_server
```

After that we transform the `tcp` packages arriving at 1089 to `udp` and redirect them to the kdc at port 88 vie

```
server$ socat tcp4-listen:1088,reuseaddr,fork UDP:localhost:88
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having to tunnel UDP traffic as well, you could force kerberos to only use tcp as following:

```
[realms]
 MY.REALM = {
  kdc = tcp/localhost:1088
  master_kdc = tcp/localhost:1088
  admin_server = tcp/localhost:1749
 }
```

And now setup your tcp/ssh tunnel as before:

```
ssh -L1088:kdc.server:88 -L1749:kdc.server:749 ssh.hop
```

Comment: If you are referring to the `kdc` on `tcp/localhost:1088`, shouldn't the tunnel map to `1088` locally? As in `ssh -L1088:kdc.server:88 [...]`

Comment: @steen you are are correct (same for the other port as well). Corrected my original reply.